# open source Load testing tool for Parallel execution

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I had used JMeter for load testing but was stuck at a point where had to execute parallel requests  which does not seem possible with it.(if possible kindly explain)

So is there any open source tool which could help. Have to increase load upto at least `1000VU`

Answer (score 1):

Depending you your hardware you may need to consider [remote (distributed) testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) where one master host orchestrates multiple JMeter slaves to create immense load.

In regards to "concurrency" JMeter offers 2 test elements to control load pattern.

- [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) - for firing X requests at the same moment of time
- [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) - to set exact load like X requests per second

Answer (score 0):

> which does not seem possible with it.(if possible kindly explain)

Increase the number of threads(users), that would be the number of simultaneous requests. The home page shows the exact example:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to try Yandex.Tank - https://github.com/yandex-load/yandex-tank. It can make to 80k parallel requests per second.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Dmitri said,  You can consider the **[distributed testing using jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)**. 

Also consider the following points,

1.Use 64 bit JVM and increse the heap memory.
2.Run load testing in non gui mode and remove all listeners (you can add it after testing to display results)
3.Use latest version of Jmeter(2.11), because of optimal resource utilization (CPU,Memory). **OR**
Use Gatling load testing tool(http://gatling-tool.org/). You can find an [comparative study of gatling Vs Jmeter](https://flood.io/blog/13-stress-testing-jmeter-and-gatling)

Comment: I have tried Distributed Testing as well,the thing is, with this multiple users will hit the server but I want multiple objects to get fetched for the same user.  Lets say if 6 articles get downloaded for an App with click on one section.With Jmeter, upon using Reg extractor one article gets fetched at a time and I want all 6 together. The reason for all this is, the response time at aggregate report is very very high in comparison to that observed while manual browsing of the app during load run

Comment: As I understood from your comment is that, You need to extract multiple strings(articles in your case) from a response. Regex extractor is capable of extract multiple strings from a response. You can find wiki page for **Extract multiple strings** in this link https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/RegularExpressions

Comment: Not completely.All extracted variables are passed on to a different request(probably next) and I have executed them in a loop which gets executed one after the other while I need to process/execute them parallely all together.From what I have done the response time gets increased which is not the actual scenario.